# LIfebook lh531 inbuilt card reader not working

Tags: card-reader

Inbuilt card reader (SD/PRO/SDHC) not working. When I insert the memory card the indicator comes for a milli second and nothing happens. When I do lspci it gives the out put which is pasted below: I use Ubuntu 11.10. Pl help

```
pro-hq@prohq-LIFEBOOK-LH531:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (rev 34)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
pro-hq@prohq-LIFEBOOK-LH531:~$
```

Comment: Run `lsusb` and post the result. `lcpci` list all PCI devices

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a card reader. I could not find a fix. The only solution I could use was use my windows laptop to copy files I needed to my mini SD card. It is stupid having to rely on another OS to make up for Ubuntu failings, but most hardware is designed to work on MS Win and not Ubuntu. Maybe in the future better driver will be developed, unfortunately if you use additional hardware and need full compatibility you'll have to use a MS Win partition, dual boot. Sorry dude, not what you want to hear...